# What dark anime show had a character with organic armour who fought for good?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to figure out the name of a show I watched between 2000 and 2004 on Cartoon Network or possibly Adult Swim.

- It was about a mystical or alien character
- He wore some kind of organic armour and fought for good.
- It was the property of some corporation (I think)

It was a very dark and mysterious show, much more mysterious and mythological than it was alien/sci-fi.

I watched a few clips of Guyver and at first I thought that might be it, but I don't believe it is. The suited character in the show I remember was much more mysterious and at best questionably human, and it wasn't about high schoolers at all. Most of all, the anime style was much more modern then Guyver and a lot of scenes took place underground in creepy places.

I also recall a clip from it that I have seen recently in an anime music video of a pale dead corpse of a girl flailing her arms and legs in a circle in order to crawl up some stairs. It was pretty creepy which is why I remember it. But I saw that scene again a few years ago in some compilation AMV.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoweredArmor

Comment: Was the armor alien, or the person who wore it?

Comment: Possibly from adult swim: FLCL, Big O, Gundam, Kikaider, candidate for goddess, which all had mobile suits/armor and air in that time time frame, but you need more details for help.

Comment: Since this was likely anime, you might have better luck asking on the [anime.SE](http://anime.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 3):

Might be Bio-Booster Armor Guyver. The  epopnymous armor *is* owned by a corporation and gets into the hand of an unwitting Highschool-Student who uses it to fight for good

Comment: The 2005 Guyver cartoon wasn't aired in the US/English until 2010 and the earlier one was never aired, just released on vhs then later dvd.

Comment: Ah, sorry. my bad then.